# Building Go Project on Windows Using Local Environment with Remote Code Storage

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I have a remote storage provided by my company where they store the codebase. I can access this storage by opening an SSH connection to the machine using VS Code. My local environment, where I have all the necessary dependencies, is on Windows. The goal is to build the Go project locally on my Windows machine.

1. How can I configure VS Code to use my local Go environment for building the project that resides on the remote machine?
2. Is it possible to set up VS Code in a way that allows me to build and run the Go code on my Windows machine while the source code is stored remotely?
3. What steps or configurations do I need to perform to achieve this setup?

I want to avoid installing Go on the remote server and leverage my local development environment. Any guidance on achieving this workflow would be highly appreciated.

---